# 3D animations using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, css-animations

On Steam there is a game called Dota 2. They had this section of "cards" that showed the characters you play. When you hover over the card, there is a really cool animation. The card lifts up and pivots towards the mouse pointer.

Pictures are attached. The red dot represents where the mouse is hovering:

Bottom-left:
[image]

Center: 
[image]

Left-center:
[image]

Currently, I have a basic version here: https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/mdyvEeg but the animation isn't working as intended.

I will also post the code at the end of this question should Codepen links not be allowed on Stackoverflow. Some of the code is redundant, but I kept it in there to gain more insight.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const card = document.querySelector('.card')
let x = document.querySelector('.x-axis')
let y = document.querySelector('.y-axis')

container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let xCoords = e.offsetX
  let yCoords = e.offsetY

  x.innerHTML = `xCoords:${xCoords}`
  y.innerHTML = `yCoords:${yCoords}`

  card.style.transform = `rotateY(${yCoords}deg) rotateX(${xCoords}deg) scale(1.1)`
})  

container.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  card.style.transform = `rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) scale(1)`
})

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
  background: grey;
}

.x-axis,
.y-axis {
  position: absolute;
}

.y-axis {
  left:100px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
}

.card {  
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;  
  border-radius: 10px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;  
  box-shadow: 10px 8px 20px -20px black;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

.container:hover  {

  .card {        
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="x-axis"></p>
<p class="y-axis"></p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wowwiki/images/d/d9/Illidan.png/revision/latest?cb=20140503134345" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide pictures of what *the top right corner to come closer to the user* means? Also, what if the user is hovering at the center of the card, what happens then? Providing basic pictures of how you want it to be (in different hover positions) will improve understanding of what you want exactly. Furthermore, do try to insert your code into a runnable snippet by using the shortcut `Ctrl+M` when you edit your post.

Comment: Added pictures and the code was edited by another individual and can now be seen in code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for. To give a 3D feel to an object, you have to use the CSS property `perspective`. Here's a working example (also available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/takenoteiamhere/pen/eYmXZMN)):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const card = document.querySelector('.card')
const output = document.querySelector('.output')
let x = document.querySelector('.x-axis')
let y = document.querySelector('.y-axis')

container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let xOffset = e.offsetX
  let yOffset = e.offsetY
  let cardHeight = card.clientHeight
  let cardWidth = card.clientWidth
  let heightCenter = Math.round(cardHeight / 2)
  let widthCenter = Math.round(cardWidth / 2)
  let rotateBaseValue = 20
  let rotateXValue = (yOffset - heightCenter) / heightCenter * rotateBaseValue
  let rotateYValue = (widthCenter - xOffset) / widthCenter * rotateBaseValue

  card.style.transform = `scale(1.1) rotateX(${rotateXValue}deg) rotateY(${rotateYValue}deg)`
})

container.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  card.style.transform = ''
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DySLFjlV4AEWf_F.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  height: 25vw;
  width: 15vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .25s linear;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container:hover .card {
  box-shadow: 10px 30px 50px -6px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/baf4a8fec55a6cb6fd7b18a7855998e4/tumblr_ply7xcI7pl1sjt61g_540.png" alt="Moonlight Cookie's Alluring Crescent Moon Costume">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As per request, I will explain how I got the formula for `rotateXValue` and `rotateYValue`.

Before getting into that, you need to know what `rotateX` and `rotateY` do. [`rotateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateX) rotates an item on the horizontal axis (x-axis) and [`rotateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY) rotates an item on the vertical axis (y-axis). Positive value on both `rotateX` and `rotateY` means that their movements are clockwise; negative means that their movements are counter-clockwise.

Try holding up a piece of paper. You'll notice that if you rotate the paper a little (doesn't matter how many degrees exactly) counter-clockwise on both x-axis and y-axis, you'll see that the paper seems exactly like when you are hovering on the top-right corner of the card. Try clockwise on both x-axis and y-axis, you'll see that the paper's pointing towards you like when you are hovering on the bottom-left corner of the card. Try all four combinations of different rotation directions.

After doing the above experiment, you can soon conclude that:

- Top-left corner: `rotateX` counter-clockwise, `rotateY` clockwise
- Top-right corner: `rotateX` and `rotateY` counter-clockwise
- Bottom-left corner: `rotateX` and `rotateY` clockwise
- Bottom-right corner: `rotateX` clockwise and `rotateY` counter-clockwise

Say that the maximum rotation is 15degrees. On the x-axis, value ranges from 15degrees to -15degrees (from left to right). On the y-axis, value ranges from -15degrees to 15degrees (from top to bottom). The card does not rotate when you're hovering in the middle of the card. Calculate the y-axis. The center is when the value is 0degree. Simply subtract the current y-offset with the center-offset and you'll get how much the distance is from the center-offset. Convert that to fraction relative to center-offset by dividing with the center-offset value. Multiply the fractional value to the maximum degrees to get how many degrees to rotate. Do the same with the x-axis (in this case, you need to invert the subtraction because the value ranges from positive to negative).

*P.S.: This one was extremely fun to make. Thanks for the idea!*

Comment: @RizaKhan I'm sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you killed it. Knocked it out of the park. Absolutely obliterated the question. 

Or if you prefer, with less hyperbole and flavor: Your answer was the correct one.

The only other thing I noticed in the original version was that there was a 'light' that was reflecting off the card. Idk how difficult that would be be to implement.

Comment: Can you please explain these two lines. How you determined this and how it works:

let rotateXValue = (yOffset - heightCenter) / heightCenter * rotateBaseValue
let rotateYValue = (widthCenter - xOffset) / widthCenter * rotateBaseValue

Thank you,

Comment: @RizaKhan Updated my answer to reflect on how to get the formula you wanted. Also, thank you for the exuberant compliment.